# Creating a Cumulative Frequency column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a frequency table and I am looking to add a cumulative frequency column to it. The first 5 rows of the table looks like this:

Type Freq
1  1201
2  3910
3  2191
4  3654
5  9822

I just want to add a cumulative frequency column to the right. I did my research and attempting the following:

Assume the first Type value is in cell A2. I created a column called Cumulative Frequency, and then in cell C2 I wrote '=A2'. In cell C3 I wrote '=A2 + A3' and in cell C4 I wrote '=A2 + A3 + A4'. I then selected the cells C2:C4 and dragged the bottom right corner to the bottom.

However, instead of Excel understanding that I was creating a Cumulative Frequency column, it simply copied similarly what I had already wrote.

C5 = A5
C6 = A5 + A6
C7 = A5 + A6 + A7
C8 = A8
etc.

Any idea how I can fix this? It's a table of around 300 rows so I don't want to type the formulas individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUM() with a variable range:

```
=SUM($A$2:$A2)
```

Note what is relative.  As this is dragged/copied down the row number in the `$A2` will change always summing the range above.

Answer (score 1):

In cell C2 write '=A2' and in cell C3 write '=**C2** + A3'. Then drag down C3. It should work :)